Create external Hive table for multiline Json
I am trying to create Hive Table for for given multiline JSON. But actual result is not similar to expected result.
Sample JSON file:
 {
      "name": "Adil Abro",
      "language": "Sindhi",
      "id": "LJRIULRNJFCNZJAJ",
      "bio": "Etiam malesuada blandit erat, eget ullamcorper risus ligula tristique libero.",
      "version": "9.32"
    }
    {
      "name": "Afonso Vilarchán",
      "language": "Galician",
      "id": "JMCL0CXNXHPL1GBC",
      "bio": "Fusce eu ultrices elit, Nunc tincidunt laoreet laoreet.",
      "version": "5.21"
    }     

Create HIVE table statement using Java:
createHQ = String.format("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (`name` string, `language` string, `id` string, `bio` string, `version` string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '_' MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' NULL DEFINED AS 'null' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION '%s' TBLPROPERTIES (\"serialization.null.format\"=\"\")", tableName, outputLocation.trim());
 

Created HIVE table - current output of this query shown:
 +--------------------------------------+-----------------------+----+----+-------+
 |name                                  |language               |id  |bio |version|
 +--------------------------------------+-----------------------+----+----+-------+
 |{                                     |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "name": "Adil Abro"                 |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "language": "Sindhi"                |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "id": "LJRIULRNJFCNZJAJ"            |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "bio": "Etiam malesuada blandit erat| eget ullamcorper..."  |null|null|null   |
 |  "version": "9.32"                   |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |}                                     |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |{                                     |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "name": "Afonso Vilarchán"          |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "language": "Galician"              |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "id": "JMCL0CXNXHPL1GBC"            |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |  "bio": "Fusce eu ultrices elit      | Nunc tincidunt ..."   |null|null|null   |
 |  "version": "5.21"                   |null                   |null|null|null   |
 |}                                     |null                   |null|null|null   |
 +--------------------------------------+-----------------------+----+----+-------+

Expected table:
each field should be there in respective column, but it's not reading like that
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+
|name                 |language          |id               |bio                    |version|
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+
| Adil Abro           |Sindhi            |LJRIULRNJFCNZJAJ | Etiam .....           | 9.32  |
| Afonso Vilarchán    |Galician          |JMCL0CXNXHPL1GBC | Fusce eu ultric.....  | 5.21  |
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+

I am trying to create hive table for multiline json data, where my expected table is not matching with actual table/output
